# Why does std::condition_variable::wait_for() throw an operation not permitted std::system_error on Windows with VS2013?

Tags: windows, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a simple test of having background threads on a GUI program that asynchronously pushes display work back onto the GUI thread once a second. It does not work on Windows, with `std::condition_variable::wait_for()` throwing a `std::system_error` of type `operation not permitted.`.

**This is with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 x64. It is not with gcc on Linux, so `-lpthread` does not count here. Existing questions on the issue (both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere) are all for gcc/Linux/`-lpthread`.** In fact, I have an equivalent test on Linux (with GTK+) and it works just fine.

Here's an example. It opens a window with a button and a multiline edit box. Every second, you should see the line `One second passed` added to the edit box. Clicking the button adds the line `Saying something` immediately. Lines should never mix.

Instead, if you run this program, you should see

```
class std::system_error caught: operation not permitted: operation not permitted
```

on the command line, and the `One second passed` messages never show up.

I am building with

```
cl /TP wincondvartest.cpp /W4 /Zi /EHsc /link /incremental:no user32.lib kernel32.lib gdi32.lib
```

What's going on? Thanks.

```
// 6 december 2015
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#define STRICT
#define STRICT_TYPED_ITEMIDS
// get Windows version right; right now Windows Vista
#define WINVER 0x0600               /* according to Microsoft's winnls.h */
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600     /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0600       /* according to Microsoft's pdh.h */
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700            /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#define NTDDI_VERSION 0x06000000    /* according to Microsoft's sdkddkver.h */
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <time.h>

HWND mainwin;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ourlock(m);
std::thread *timeThread;

bool wait(void)
try {
    return cv.wait_for(ourlock, std::chrono::seconds(1)) == std::cv_status::timeout;
} catch (const std::exception &e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s caught: %s\n", typeid (e).name(), e.what());
    return false;       // kill the thread
}

void threadproc(void)
{
    while (wait())
        PostMessageW(mainwin, WM_APP, 0, 0);
}

HWND edit;

void appendline(const WCHAR *wc)
{
    LRESULT n;

    n = SendMessageW(edit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    SendMessageW(edit, EM_SETSEL, n, n);
    SendMessageW(edit, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM) wc);
}

HWND button;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (lParam == (LPARAM) button)
            appendline(L"Saying something\n");
        break;
    case WM_APP:
        appendline(L"One second passed\n");
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        cv.notify_all();
        timeThread->join();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void)
{
    WNDCLASSW wc;
    RECT r;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof (WNDCLASSW));
    wc.lpszClassName = L"mainwin";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndproc;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    r.left = 0;
    r.top = 0;
    r.right = 10 + 300 + 10;
    r.bottom = 10 + 20 + 5 + 195 + 10;
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&r, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE, 0);
    mainwin = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"mainwin", L"mainwin",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    button = CreateWindowExW(0,
        L"button", L"Say Something",
        BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        10, 10,
        300, 20,
        mainwin, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    edit = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        L"edit", L"",
        ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL,
        10, 10 + 20 + 5,
        300, 195,
        mainwin, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    timeThread = new std::thread(threadproc);

    ShowWindow(mainwin, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mainwin);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The mutex is originally locked by the main thread (by way of `ourlock` being a global variable). I'm pretty sure it's illegal to attempt to unlock it on a different thread, as `cv.wait_for(ourlock)` would attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by trying to unlock a mutex locked by a different thread. `ourlock` is originally constructed on the main thread, being a global variable, at which point it locks `m`. Then you pass it to `cv.wait_for` on the second thread. This is explicitly prohibited:

> **[thread.condition.condvar]**
>
> ```
> template <class Rep, class Period>
>     cv_status wait_for(unique_lock<mutex>& lock,
>                        const chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& rel_time);
> ```
>
> **25** *Requires:* `lock.owns_lock()` is true and `lock.mutex()` is **locked by the calling thread**...

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Ah, I see. I remember seeing that the mutex needed to be locked on entry to `wait_for()`, but somehow missed the "calling thread" bit. Thanks!

Comment: "Appears to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.